# Create Multiple Graphs from One Dataframe - R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, dplyr, timeserieschart

I am trying to create a workflow that collects information (stock ticker data, 30 different tickers, with three different prices associated with an individual ticker) from a website, cleans the data (adds a date column relative to the day the information was collected), pushes it into a master file `tsibble` dataframe that holds new data points everyday and then graphs the price ranges on individual plots compiled onto one page.

Example df for one day below to be pushed into master df to hold all the data:

```
df <- data.frame(ticker = c("XLU", "XLK", "XLF", "XLE", "XLP"),
             buy_price = c(62.00, 68.00, 37.00, 55.00, 41.00),
             sale_price = c(64.00, 71.00, 42.00, 60.00, 45.00),
             close_price = c(63.00, 70.00, 38.00, 56.00, 43.00),
             date = c("April 29th, 2021", "April 29th, 2021", "April 29th, 2021", "April 29th, 2021", "April 29th, 2021"))
```

Second day of data:

```
df2 <- data.frame(ticker = c("XLU", "XLK", "XLF", "XLE", "XLP"),
                 buy_price = c(63.00, 69.00, 38.00, 53.00, 44.00),
                 sale_price = c(66.00, 77.00, 47.00, 63.00, 48.00),
                 close_price = c(65.00, 74.00, 39.00, 55.00, 45.00),
                 date = c("April 30th, 2021", "April 30th, 2021", "April 30th, 2021", "April 30th, 2021", "April 30th, 2021"))
```

DF Master file: `rbind(df, df2)`

```
       ticker buy_price sale_price close_price             date
1     XLU        62         64          63 April 29th, 2021
2     XLK        68         71          70 April 29th, 2021
3     XLF        37         42          38 April 29th, 2021
4     XLE        55         60          56 April 29th, 2021
5     XLP        41         45          43 April 29th, 2021
6     XLU        63         66          65 April 30th, 2021
7     XLK        69         77          74 April 30th, 2021
8     XLF        38         47          39 April 30th, 2021
9     XLE        53         63          55 April 30th, 2021
10    XLP        44         48          45 April 30th, 2021
```

I had used `facet_wrap_paginate` to facet by stock ticker name, and create multiple graphs. However, I do not have the fine control over the axes and individual plots that I need when using a facet, so I must use an approach of plotting each ticker individually and compiling onto the same pages. I had used the code below:

```
for(i in 1:4){
    rr_plot <- ggplot(rr_tsibble, aes(x = DATE, color = TREND)) +
    geom_point(aes(y = BUY.TRADE), size = 1.5) +
    geom_point(aes(y = SELL.TRADE), size = 1.5) +
    geom_point(aes(y = PREV.CLOSE), color = "black", size = 1, shape = 1) +
    ggforce::facet_wrap_paginate(~TICKER,
                                 nrow = 2,
                                 ncol = 4,
                                 scales = "free_y",
                                 page = i) +
    scale_y_continuous()
    print(rr_plot)
```

to achieve this. The original datafram has ~30 induvidual tickers with the same 30 added to the df the next day, and then 30 more. I have tried using `dplyr` to `group_by` and plot, although I haven't been to acheive desired results. I do not think that creating 30 plots manually with `ggplot2` is very efficent, there must be a for loop that can allow for the selection of only certain tickers to then plot all of the data and use `cowplot` and `extraGrid` to compile all 30 generated plots. Any help or thoughts on how to accomplish this would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Could you give an example of what you would like to do with the axis?

Comment: So some of the stock data, has prices or values that range from 1.0-1.9, and also 43,000-56,000, and I would like to be able to set individual breaks, with finer detail for small values and larger breaks for the larger values and also extend the y-axis in + and - directions about 10% of the maximum value for that ticker so i dont run into an issue of the plotted data being at the top of the y-axis when facetting as shown here...(GBP/USD and NYXBT figure)(https://imgur.com/zRjtmyJ)

Comment: @VitaminB16 would you suggest to achieve this through way of a nested data frame and plot all the nested variables

Comment: I can't say that I understand what the problem is. I've created a data frame called `rr_tsibble` with 10 days of data, where one of the tickers has values >100k and other tickers have values ~50. I've run your ggplot code with `facet_wrap(~ticker,scales = "free_y") + scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks())` instead of pagination and it all looked ok to me. I use `pretty_breaks()` whenever possible, but it's probably unrelated to your problem.

Comment: @VitaminB16 when you are running the faceted plot, does pretty_breaks allow you to specify the breaks and y-axis range for each individual plot?

Comment: No it doesn't, it just makes the breaks look more meaningful: e.g. `1,2,3,4,5,6` instead of `1,2.25,3.5,4.75,6`. Also note that because of `scales = "free_y"` inside the `facet_wrap()`, any modification to the y-axis will remove points from the plot, because the y-axis range is `(min(y), max(y))` ±5% on either side.

Comment: Instead of ±5% you can have something else by playing around with the `expand` argument of `scale_y_continuous()`. For example, `expand = c(0,0)` will make the y limits strictly `(min(y), max(y))`.

Comment: If you want to select a custom range on the y-axis, you have to be specific about what you want. For example, you can make the y-axis range to be the minimum and the maximum values of y in the past 2 days, or something else. So please specify the specific rule you would like the axis range to follow. Different specifications may require completely different solutions.

Comment: @VitaminB16 I am getting an error `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale` when running the code, changing to scale_y_discrete loses the correct scaing of the y-axis amongst the faceted tickers

Comment: What is on your y-axis? Can you supply data?

Comment: Some of my data was accidentally coerced to a chr string, so couldn't plot categorical data on the y. Figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generated some random data with some 30 random tickers across 4 days:

```
r <- function() {abs(c(rnorm(29,50,2),100000)*rnorm(1,10,1))}
tickers = sapply(1:30, function(x) toupper(paste0(sample(letters, 3), collapse = "")))
df <- data.frame(ticker = tickers,
                 buy_price = r(),
                 sale_price = r(),
                 close_price = r(),
                 date = rep("April 29th, 2021",30))
df2 <- data.frame(ticker = tickers,
                  buy_price = r(),
                  sale_price = r(),
                  close_price = r(),
                  date = rep("April 30th, 2021",30))
df3 <- data.frame(ticker = tickers,
                  buy_price = r(),
                  sale_price = r(),
                  close_price = r(),
                  date = rep("May 1st, 2021",30))
df4 <- data.frame(ticker = tickers,
                  buy_price = r(),
                  sale_price = r(),
                  close_price = r(),
                  date = rep("May 2nd, 2021",30))
rr_tsibble <- rbind(df, df2, df3, df4)
```

Converted `date` to date format:

```
rr_tsibble$date = as.Date(gsub("st|th|nd","",rr_tsibble$date), "%b %d, %Y")
```

Add the `addUnits()` function for formatting the large numbers:

```
addUnits <- function(n) {
  labels <- ifelse(n < 1000, n,  # less than thousands
                   ifelse(n < 1e6, paste0(round(n/1e3,3), 'k'),  # in thousands
                          ifelse(n < 1e9, paste0(round(n/1e6,3), 'M'),  # in millions
                                 ifelse(n < 1e12, paste0(round(n/1e9), 'B'), # in billions
                                        ifelse(n < 1e15, paste0(round(n/1e12), 'T'), # in trillions
                                               'too big!'
                                        )))))}
```

Make the list of plots:

```
plotlist <- list()
for (i in 1:ceiling(30/8))
{
  plotlist[[i]] <- ggplot(rr_tsibble, aes(x = date)) +
    geom_point(aes(y = buy_price), size = 1.5) +
    geom_point(aes(y = sale_price), size = 1.5) +
    geom_point(aes(y = close_price), color = "black", size = 1, shape = 1) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks(), labels = addUnits) +
    ggforce::facet_wrap_paginate(~ticker,
                                 nrow = 2,
                                 ncol = 4,
                                 scales = "free_y",
                                 page = i)
}
```

There are 4 pages in total, each stored as an element of `plotlist` list. For example, the final page is the 4th element, and looks like this:

```
plotlist[[4]]
```

[image]

Comment: I have the `scales` package loaded, but I the `pretty_breaks()` is not found?

Comment: Try `scales::pretty_breaks()`